# Simple conceptual Fundamental Thm of Calculus question

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, integration, contour-integration

When applying the Fundamental Thm of Calculus in complex analysis, what does it mean for an open connected set to contain a loop? For example, does my red-color open annulus contain the black colour loop? I think so, but I'm struggling with understanding this:
[image]

When asked to integrate $\frac 1{(z-5)}$ around a circle centred at 5, why can't I use the Fundamental Thm of Calculus? After all, the function is continuous in the red annulus , and furthermore, its primitive $\ln z$ is analytic throughout the annulus which does not touch the negative real axis.

Comment: Well, there you go: the complex function $\,\text{Log}\, z\,$ *cannot*  be analytic in any domain containing zero in it's interior, since as we "go around" that black loop the argument of complex numbers increases and then...

Comment: Its primitive would be $\ln(z-5)$, which is **not** analytic in the annulus. You need a branch cut.

Comment: @Ryan , zero $=0\,$ *the* zero. In your case, your function would be Log$\,(z-5) \,$ , which would have a serious problem at $\,z=5\,$ , so your annulus better won't contain this point in its interior...but a circle centered at $\,z=5\,$ does contain it...

Comment: @DonAntonio haha thanks. So, $\log (z-5)$ is analytic only on $\mathbb C - [-\infty,5]$, right?

Comment: Indeed so, @Ryan...but choosing that branch cut won't then allow you to integrate *around* the circle you wanted, no matter how small its radius is, as it'd intersect the cut. You better calculate this thing as usual complex line  integral.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks for clearing that up. Prior to this, I had blindly accepted without thinking that any log function is simply non-analytic on the nonpositive real axis. I'm glad I asked.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental theorem of calculus is applied to a special contour: intervals of the real line.  And it applies to functions that have an antiderivative, or primitive.  In the complex plane, we have Cauchy's Theorem which states that such nicely behaved functions ("analytic") may be integrated by evaluating its antiderivative at the endpoints of a contour, no matter the shape of the contour.

In your case, the function $1/(z-5)$ has a pole in the interior of the black contour. By Cauchy's theorem, the value of the integral is $i 2 \pi$.  You can see this from a parametrization $z=5+r e^{i \phi}$.  Now, suppose you evaluate the integral via a Fundamental Theorem of calculus mindset: let's say we want to evaluate $\log{(z-5)}$ at the beginning and end of the contour.   Parametrize by $z=5 + r e^{i \phi}$, and so we will be subtracting the value of the antiderivative at $\phi=0$ from the value at $\phi=2 \pi$:

$$\log{(r e^{i 2 \pi})} - \log{(r e^{i 0} )} = \log{r} + i 2 \pi - \log{r} - i 0 = i 2 \pi$$

It is the multivaluedness of the log function that causes the nonzero value.  But you see that it all agrees and provides for a consistent basis for computation.

A word about your annulus: yes, $1/(z-5)$ is analytic throughout your annulus.  The integral about the boundary of the annulus is indeed zero: you also have to integrate about the inner circle in the opposite direction, so the integral is $i 2 \pi - i 2 \pi = 0$.